# How to write one CASE function two THEN method at the same time END AS Two NEW column depend on THEN action

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

```
SELECT Emp.IntegrationFieldOne AS LocationCode, Emp.EmployeeId, 
Emp.FirstName + ' '+ Emp.LastName as 'EmployeeName',
CASE WHEN ( (ORSet.Rate) =1.5  ) THEN 
Sum(OT.Minutes) 
END AS '1.5HRSMinutes',

CASE WHEN( ORSet.Rate =2  ) THEN 
Sum(OT.Minutes) 
END AS '2HRSMinutes'

FROM [CemexDB_CP_Test].[TimeAttendance].[OvertimeTransaction] OT 
INNER JOIN [HumanResource].[Employee] Emp ON OT.EmployeeId = Emp.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN [CemexDB_CP_Test].[TimeAttendance].[OvertimeRateSettingDetail] 
ORSet ON ORSet.OvertimeRateSettingId= OT.OvertimeType

GROUP BY Emp.EmployeeId,Emp.FirstName,Emp.LastName,Emp.IntegrationFieldOne,ORSet.Rate[!
```

[This is Output picture click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sko9I.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sko9I.png)

This is the out put but i want same row depend same id. but here each id has 2 
  row how to handle it

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Emp.IntegrationFieldOne AS LocationCode, Emp.EmployeeId, 
       Emp.FirstName + ' '+ Emp.LastName as EmployeeName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORSet.Rate = 1.5 THEN OT.Minutes END) AS [1.5HRSMinutes],
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORSet.Rate = 2 THEN OT.Minutes END) AS [2HRSMinutes]
FROM [CemexDB_CP_Test].[TimeAttendance].[OvertimeTransaction] OT INNER JOIN
     [HumanResource].[Employee] Emp
     ON OT.EmployeeId = Emp.EmployeeId INNER JOIN
     [CemexDB_CP_Test].[TimeAttendance].[OvertimeRateSettingDetail] 
ORSet
     ON ORSet.OvertimeRateSettingId= OT.OvertimeType
GROUP BY Emp.EmployeeId, Emp.FirstName, Emp.LastName, Emp.IntegrationFieldOne;
```

Comment: it's showing error "'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name.". here [1.5HRSMinutes] this column is not a predefined column

Comment: @Av.Raj . . . There were unbalanced parentheses.  Regardless, `SUM()` *is* a built-in function.

Comment: yes i'm notify it and balanced it but then also it's not working

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff